# Amchart axis reverted order

Tags: jquery, charts, amcharts

I'm trying to create a chart from remote source data, but I'm facing quite a weird problem... The resulting chart is different according to the `minimum` and `maximum` options I set.

Here you can see the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YuriJF/f69d5882/1/), actually working with the following options:

```
var WS_SENSOR = {
    "fillColor":"#bf55ec",
    "yaxis_min":"985", //this will be used as `minimum` value
    "yaxis_max":"995"  //this will be used as `maximum` value
};
```

But, you can see where the problem is occurring, if you change them to this:

```
var WS_SENSOR = {
    "fillColor":"#bf55ec",
    "yaxis_min":"980", //this will be used as `minimum` value
    "yaxis_max":"1005"  //this will be used as `maximum` value
};
```

Unexpectedly, the y axis (which should grow bigger from bottom to top) switched from ascending order to descending order...
What caused this behaviour? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because they are strings. You should change the `yaxis_min` and `yaxis_max` values to be numbers. It's reversed because if you compare string numbers, "980" is bigger than "1005".

```
console.log("980" > "1005"); //true
console.log(980 > 1005); //false
```

Change `WS_SENSOR` to:

```
var WS_SENSOR = {
    "fillColor":"#bf55ec",
    "yaxis_min": 980, //this will be used as `minimum` value
    "yaxis_max": 1005  //this will be used as `maximum` value
};
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x89mzt7q/)